# Fallback function fails when ethers sent from metamask

Tags: erc-20, metamask, payable, fallback-function

This is my code snippet for fallback function, If I use it by explicity using "fallback" function on Remix, then equivalent no of tokens do come in my wallet but if I send ethers via metamask directly to contract address then it fails always. See transaction hash: https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0x0324500811aa9ee4b6fe0293458eab7b13c10e0cc4bc45b8c892bc6b318730f4

```
/**
 * Fallback function when sending ether to the contract
 * Gas use: 
*/
function () external payable {
    uint256 amount = msg.value;                                                     // amount that was sent
    require(amount > 0);                                                            // need to send some ETH
    balances[msg.sender] = balances[msg.sender].add(amount.mul(1000));              // mint new tokens
    _totalSupply = _totalSupply.add(amount.mul(1000));                              // track the supply
    depositor[msg.sender].time = now;
    depositor[msg.sender].amount = msg.value;
    emit Transfer(address(0), msg.sender, amount.mul(1000));                        // notify of the transfer event
    emit Deposited(msg.sender, amount);                                             // notify deposit event
}
```

Comment: The transaction fee is too low. I tried to send some ether and the first time Metamask erroneously said 21k gas, when I tried a second time it show 136k perhaps it's a bug in Metamask.

Comment: @Ismael  yes, I observed that once I try to send some ethers it give me 110k fee and it went successful then I tried again it showed 21k fee and transaction failed, what shall I do currently? Can I somehow fix the gas fee?

Comment: In Metamask there's an advanced option that allows to set the gas amount and gas price.

Comment: @Ismael, is there a way I can make it default in contract so metamask always require that amount of gas? because all users will not know what optimal gas to use

Comment: No, it is not possible for a contract to set the gas price.

Answer (score 1):

Your fallback function does too much for the 2,300 gas stipend. As a general heuristic, avoid setting state variables in fallback functions.

You need something like:

```
function deposit() external payable { ...
```

Hope it helps.